# Hover Menu is overlap with Dropdown field -Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular11

[Over lap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmNqb.png)

Step 1: I open Dropdown in my screen (it's consider component1)
Step 2: just hover my menu .(My menu open during hover on it)

both Dropdowns are overlapping.

If any way to restrict my menu open during other dropdowns are open

I tryied z-index in may way but it not work for me.

Comment: Are you using any angular style framework like angular-material ? Can you also share your html and css code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.